# Can't open front camera while using ARCore with the back camera on some devices

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, arcore

I'm developing an [Open Source App](https://github.com/HandyP94/ARMirror) in Unity to play around with ARCore. In it I use the following code to display video being capture from the front facing camera on a plane placed in the environment of the user in AR.

```
public class MirrorController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private WebCamTexture webCamTexture;

    public void Play()
    {
        if (webCamTexture == null)
        {
            WebCamDevice[] devices = WebCamTexture.devices;
            foreach (WebCamDevice device in devices)
            {
                if (device.isFrontFacing)
                {

                    webCamTexture = new WebCamTexture(device.name);

                    GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = webCamTexture;
                    webCamTexture.Play();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This worked fine when I tested it on a Pixel 2, but when I tried the app on a Samsung Galaxy S8,  I got the following warning in the log:
`W/CameraBase: An error occurred while connecting to camera 1: Status(-8): '8: connectHelper:1647: Too many cameras already open, cannot open camera "1"'`
It seems to be raised, when calling `webCamTexture.Play()`.

I couldn't find anything about this error on the internet. I find it especially weird, because the S8's camera app has a feature where you can take a picture using both cameras at the same time.

Does anyone know how this could be resolved?

Comment: I think it is hardware-dependent and if the manufacturer enable in the API. However, it seems that this should be better supported in Android P - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraMetadata.html#REQUEST_AVAILABLE_CAPABILITIES_LOGICAL_MULTI_CAMERA